# Is there a way to inject the ITurnContext to access the state?

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

I'm looking for the way to inject ITurnContext into my application layer to access current conversation and user state. Currently, the context is only accessible within Bot or Dialog as method parameter. That makes the application abstraction layer not as clear as usually possible.

Or do I need to implement a custom ITurnContext?

Comment: Could you please check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-context)? try i that helps.

Comment: @Paul Reichedt - are you still blocked on this? could you please share more details on what you are tried so far?